# How to calculate return to depot time and make it hard constraint

Tags: optaplanner, drools-planner

I am using the TimeWindowed version of the vehicle routing and I added to the vehicle an endOfShift time. I want to calculate the time of return to depot and make it hard constraint. 
The returnToDepotTime is calculate in the ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener, and I also changed the drl file I added

```
rule "returnToDepotBeforeEndOfShift"
when
    Vehicle(endOfShift < returnToDepotTime, $endOfShift : endOfShift, $returnToDepotTime : returnToDepotTime)
then
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, $endOfShift - $returnToDepotTime.intValue());  end
```

The problem is that OptaPlanner does not take returnToDepotTime into consideration and it is calculated but not taken by the hard constrains calculation. Any idea what to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener to also adjust the `Vehicle`'s `returnHomeTime` for the `Customer` where `getNextCustomer()` is `null`.

If the `scoreDirector` is properly notified (before/afterVarChanged methods) that the `Vehicle`'s `returnHomeTime` changed, the rules will update accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!  I added the `scoreDirector` notifications (before/afterVarChanged) and I got the error:  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The variableName (returnToDepotTime) for entityClass (interface com.test.domain.Standstill) does not exists as a property (getter/setter) on that class. `  In Vehicle the getter is defined with: `@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener.class, sources = { @CustomShadowVariable.Source(variableName = "vehicle") })
public Integer getReturnToDepotTime()... `  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It says for entityClass Standstill, not Vehicle. Not sure why the exact problem is, but it says that it trying to bind to Standstill.returnToDepotTime instead of Vehicle.returnToDepotTime. Although Vehicle extends Standstill and OptaPlanner supports polymorphism, it's a valid error (because Standstill does not extend Vehicle)

Comment: After I added the Vehicle class as an entity in  vehicleRoutingSolverConfig.xml and changed the `@CustomShadowVariable.Source(variableName = "returnToDepotTime")` it gives me `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.domain.Vehicle cannot be cast to com.test.domain.Customer` in `scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(vehicle,"returnToDepotTime");`.  Why does it try to cast Vehicle to customer and how to change it? I am doing all these in the method `updateVehicle` is this correct I I have make new method only for the return to Depot time?

Comment: Niko, could you, please, attach your code? I would like to see it. I had been implementing similar problem few weeks ago so I might help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Hi @Snukra thank you very much I solved it with a workaround I am saving everything in the last customer. 
But I want to know where was my problem :) 
So here is the important part of the vehicle object:

```
@PlanningEntity(difficultyComparatorClass = VehicleDifficultyComparator.class)
@XStreamAlias("Vehicle")
public class Vehicle extends AbstractPersistable implements Standstill {

Integer returnToDepotTime;

@CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener.class, sources = { @CustomShadowVariable.Source(variableName = "returnToDepotTime") })

public Integer getReturnToDepotTime() {
    return returnToDepotTime;
}

public void setReturnToDepotTime(Integer returnToDepotTime) {
    this.returnToDepotTime = returnToDepotTime;
}
```

}

and this is the ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener:

```
public class ArrivalTimeUpdatingVariableListener implements
    VariableListener<Customer> {

public void beforeEntityAdded(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,
        Customer customer) {
    // Do nothing
}

public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,
        Customer customer) {
    updateVehicle(scoreDirector, customer);
}

public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,
        Customer customer) {
    // Do nothing
}

public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,
        Customer customer) {
    updateVehicle(scoreDirector, customer);
}

public void beforeEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,
        Customer customer) {
    // Do nothing
}

public void afterEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,
        Customer customer) {
    // Do nothing
}

protected void updateVehicle(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,
        Customer sourceCustomer) {
    Standstill previousStandstill = sourceCustomer.getPreviousStandstill();
    Integer departureTime = null;
    Customer shadowCustomer = sourceCustomer;
    Integer arrivalTime = 0;

    Vehicle vehicle = null;
    vehicle = sourceCustomer.getVehicle();

    // here the start times are used
    if (previousStandstill instanceof Customer) {
        departureTime = ((Customer) previousStandstill).getDepartureTime();

        arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(sourceCustomer, departureTime);
    } else if (previousStandstill instanceof Vehicle) {
        vehicle = (Vehicle) previousStandstill;
        arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTimeFirstCustomer(sourceCustomer,
                vehicle);
    }

    while (shadowCustomer != null
            && ObjectUtils.notEqual(shadowCustomer.getArrivalTime(),
                    arrivalTime)) {
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowCustomer, "arrivalTime");
        shadowCustomer.setArrivalTime(arrivalTime);     
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowCustomer, "arrivalTime");

        departureTime = shadowCustomer.getDepartureTime();
        if (shadowCustomer.getNextCustomer() == null) {
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(shadowCustomer,
                    "returnTimeToDepotIfLastOnTour");
            //scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(vehicle,
            //      "returnToDepotTime");

            int returnTimeToDepot = shadowCustomer.getArrivalTime()
                    + shadowCustomer.getServiceDuration()
                    + shadowCustomer.getTravelTimeTo(vehicle.getDepot());
            vehicle.setReturnToDepotTime(returnTimeToDepot);
            shadowCustomer
                    .setReturnTimeToDepotIfLastOnTour(returnTimeToDepot);
            shadowCustomer.setEndOfShiftOfVehicle(vehicle.getEndOfShift());

            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(shadowCustomer,
                    "returnTimeToDepotIfLastOnTour");
            //scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(vehicle,
            //      "returnToDepotTime");
        }

        shadowCustomer = shadowCustomer.getNextCustomer();
        arrivalTime = calculateArrivalTime(shadowCustomer, departureTime);
    }
}

private Integer calculateArrivalTimeFirstCustomer(Customer customer,
        Vehicle vehicle) {
    // calculate the earliest possible arrival time for this customer and
    // this vehicle
    int arrivalTime = vehicle.getStartOfShift()
            + customer.getLocation().getTravelTime(
                    vehicle.getStartLocation());

    // if the time is before the redy time of a conatiner we take the ready
    // time of a customer
    if (customer.getReadyTime() > arrivalTime) {
        arrivalTime = customer.getReadyTime();
    }
    return arrivalTime;
}

private Integer calculateArrivalTime(Customer customer,
        Integer previousDepartureTime) {
    if (customer == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (previousDepartureTime == null) {
        // PreviousStandstill is the Vehicle, so we leave from the Depot
        // at
        // the best suitable time
        int maxTime = Math.max(customer.getReadyTime(),
                customer.getTravelTimeToPreviousStandstill());
        return maxTime;
    }
    int arrivalTime = previousDepartureTime
            + customer.getTravelTimeToPreviousStandstill();
    return arrivalTime;

}
```

}

The commented `scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(vehicle, "returnToDepotTime");` and `scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(vehicle, "returnToDepotTime");` return the error.
Do you any have idea why?

Comment: I am sorry I had been travelling a lot today and I had no time to look on it. I will check it tomorrow. Can you please also add stack trace for me? It could lead me to the problem.

Comment: would it be possible to attach your whole example package in .zip file with stack trace? I am trying to reproduce your problem but it would be much faster if I have your source code.